# java user interface calling python functions?

Tags: java, python, user-interface

I have a program in python using opencv, that detect movements with your eyes. I want to make a user interface with java that calls functions to this python program and then do stuff depending of the return values. It´s this possible? Is there a better solution than using java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Python from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674122/call-python-from-java)

Comment: Why not just write the user interface in Python? Python has tkinter preinstalled. If you don't like that, there's PyQt/PySide/PySide2, GObject, Kivy, wxPython, native bindings for Cocoa and Windows, and a zillion other options. Or you can write a web service with a simple web UI.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PyQt5 or PySide to directly program an UI with Python, it would be easier that way.